# can server locale settings affect JSON parsing (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, json, redis

I have an issue with a script that is parsing some data which is stored in Redis, the particular hash of data has this in a string:

```
\u00a3575,000. which is £575,000
```

Redis is storing it as a £ when i pull it out. But when I pass the string to JSON.parse it returns an error saying:

```
Unexpected error while processing request: "\xC2" on US-ASCII
```

I have been through the server and tested it on our UAT platform and it is fine, it parses fine and returns exactly what I expect, however on the live server which is the same as the UAT server (Ruby version, RVM version, Redis version) it gives the above error.

I have been through the server settings and the only thing I can see different is the locale settings (Ubuntu 12.04)

```
on UAT its set to en_GB.UTF-8 
on live its set to en_US.UTF-8
```

Before I left the office I changed the locale settings, but ran out of time to reboot the server and can't now until tomorrow morning (its IP locked for ssh to the office). However like most coders I know, I can't stop thinking about the problem, hence coming to ask here if it can make a difference. If it can't can anyone point me in the right direction to come up with a solution?

ps. I did add this line:

```
result = result.force_encoding(Encoding::UTF_8)
```

which worked but feel that, as I didn't need to do this on UAT, it feels wrong to make a code change like that to bend to a problem with the environment.

many thanks

ops: if this helps answer why i am getting the error, then: my output from rvm info
ruby-2.1.1:

```
  system:
    uname:       "Linux ip-10-82-168-126 3.2.0-54-virtual #82-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 10 20:31:18 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"
    system:      "ubuntu/12.04/x86_64"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:         " => not installed"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.25.27 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "3 hours 15 minutes 33 seconds ago"
    path:         "/usr/local/rvm"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "2.1.1p76"
    date:         "2014-02-24"
    platform:     "x86_64-linux"
    patchlevel:   "2014-02-24 revision 45161"
    full_version: "ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-linux]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1"
    ruby:         "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local.rvm/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1"
    GEM_PATH:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1"
    IRBRC:        "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

Comment: Your encodings are screwed up somewhere. You have `\u00a3` which is a Unicode pound sign. Then somehow you have `\xc2` (a `Â` in ISO 8859-1 *and* Windows CP1252) claiming to be US-ASCII (i.e. seven bit ASCII) when it has the eighth bit set. I mention ISO 8859-1 and Windows CP1252 because they're common encodings that pop when you're expecting UTF-8. There is a lot of confusion here.

Comment: Thanks, i just added a puts data.encoding to what is coming out of Redis, and i am getting US-ASCII so something is defo messed up. just need to try and work out what could be causing it

Comment: Is Redis giving you `\u00a3` as five separate characters or is that a JavaScript-style ASCII representation of a pound sign?

Comment: In UTF-8, `£` is the two bytes `0xC2 0xA3`. If this string is somehow treated as US-ASCII it will not be valid and Ruby will give an error if you try to do certain things with it. (If you interpret those bytes as ISO-8859-1 or CP-1252 it will appear as `Â£`.)

Comment: @muistooshort Its weird, if i do a puts on the data that comes out from redis i see £ if i do puts on the data.encoding i see US-ASCII, the error gets thrown when i do JSON.parse data. is there a way of doing puts data.raw ? cis thats the only way i can tell if redis is giving me \u00a3

Comment: @matt Thanks for pointing that out, now the 0xC2 makes sense. Looks like you're getting a UTF-8 string out of Redis but someone somewhere is incorrectly assuming that it is getting US-ASCII. Can you specify the encoding when you connect Redis?

Comment: Are you using the official redis client? If so, that [sets the encoding to `Encoding.default_external`](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/blob/v3.1.0/lib/redis/connection/command_helper.rb#L35), which by default is [set by the locale](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Encoding.html#method-c-default_external-3D), although I don’t know exactly how Ruby determines that. (I note that in your question both locales are using `UTF-8`. How are you getting those values?). Also, is this a Rails app? Rails sets the `default_external` to UTF-8, so in that case there must be something else happening.

Comment: @matt No its not a rails app, its a Ruby API using Grape and redis as the data store. It is also the official client. i will look into the encoding.default_external thanks

Comment: Did you work out what’s happening here? I’m curious about what’s going on. It looks like locale could be affecting it, but both machines locales appear to be UTF-8.

Comment: @matt Unfortunately, i never did get to the bottom of the issue, we think it wasn't helped that the chap who set the server up wasn't the most clued up of developers. To be honest we wanted to reset the server up to see if that would have sorted it, but we weren't able to. In the end I had to use the force_encoding(Encoding::UTF_8) on the string coming out of Redis.